# Python decorator not acting as expected

Tags: python, python-decorators

Just playing with decorators, and have a simple example I made.  I was expecting that every time I called a method, the method name would be added to the list.

```
python_func_calls = []

def log_func_call(func):
    python_func_calls.append(func.__name__)
    return func

@log_func_call
def print_a():
    print('I am the a function...')
    
@log_func_call
def print_b():
    print('I am the b function...')
    
print_a()
print_b()
print_b()
print_a()

print(python_func_calls)
```

But this gives me the following content of python_func_calls:

```
['print_a', 'print_b']
```

I had thought there would be 4 entries in the list, as decorated functions were called 4 times.

Comment: The decorator's only called twice, once for each function you decorate. It's **not** called when you invoke the functions; it just returns the functions themselves, they're not wrapped at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decorator syntax is similar to:

```py
def print_a():
    ...

print_a = log_func_call(print_a)
```

Hence, the decorator is called exactly once with the target function as an argument. If you want the decorated version to do extra work for every function call, you need to create a wrapper function inside the decorator that does two things:

1. Do the extra work: `python_func_calls.append(func.__name__)`
2. Invoke the decorated function and return whatever that function returns: `return func(*args, **kwargs)`.

The following decorator implements these requirements:

```py
from functools import wraps

python_func_calls = []

def log_func_call(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        python_func_calls.append(func.__name__)
        return func(*args, **kwars)

    return wrapper
```

Note that the decorator uses another decorator [`wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) which adjusts the metadata of the `wrapper` function to mimic that of the decorated function `func` (e.g. signature and docstring).

Comment: Thanks print_a = log_func_call(print_a) makes sense now

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new function and return *that* from the decorator. Inside this function, call the passed in wrapped function. For example:

```
from functools import wraps

python_func_calls = []

def log_func_call(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        python_func_calls.append(func.__name__)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

@log_func_call
def print_a():
    print('I am the a function...')
    
@log_func_call
def print_b():
    print('I am the b function...')
    
print_a()
print_b()
print_b()
print_a()

print(python_func_calls)
```

This gives `python_func_calls` as:

```
['print_a', 'print_b', 'print_b', 'print_a']
```

The reason this works is that the function returned by the decorator replaces the wrapped function. So it gets called each time, rather than just when the decorator is created.In your original code, you return the original function...so nothing changes when you call the function.

Comment: You should also change the name of the wrapper function to that of the original function so that the code further down the line isn't affected. (e.g. `wrapped.__name__ = func.__name__`)

Comment: Fair point, @2pichar I was trying to keep it simple, but probably should make a proper decorator … edited.

Answer (score 0):

The decorator is called at the function definition so twice total:

```
python_func_calls = []

def log_func_call(func):
    python_func_calls.append(func.__name__)
    return func

@log_func_call #first call
def print_a():
    print('I am the a function...')
    
@log_func_call #second call
def print_b():
    print('I am the b function...')
    
print_a() #decorator not called
print_b() #decorator not called
print_b() #decorator not called
print_a() #decorator not called

print(python_func_calls)
```

So despite 4 function calls there are only 2 decorator calls.

Comment: This answer just pastes the OP's original code. How does this help get their desired result?

Comment: @Mark I was explaining the result as the OP seemed confused about it and wanted an explanation. If this was not the intent of the question then it was unclear.